# A diophantine and number theory $5b^2+5c^2+6bc=x^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A diophantine and number theory $5b^2+5c^2+6bc=x^2$
My approach: Tried to find some inequalities but couldn't progress after a while. Found a recurrence by assuming a to be a variable and other's as constants then did the same with b. Now with that recurrence a,b we can of course generate infinite solutions but there is no proof of termination and neither can we proceed without base solution. I want a general solution and answer to whether this has infinite solutions or finite ones? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you share the recurrences you claim to have found?

Comment: This is equivalent to $$(5b+3c)^2+16c^2=5x^2$$ or $$u^2-5x^2=-16c^2$$ with the added condition that $u\equiv 3c\pmod 5.$

Comment: Or you can write it as $(5b+3c)^2+(4c)^2=5x^2,$ and use properties of Gaussian integers to find solutions.

Comment: This is equivalent to finding rational points on the ellipse $5x^2 + 6xy + 5y^2 = 1$ (other than the trivial solution $b=c=x=0$).  To do that, you can use the method of taking a line with rational slope $m$ through the point $(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$, and finding the other intersection with the ellipse.

Comment: @Henrik it's less of recurrence and more of a solution conversion yet s.p.s x,y,z is a solution then automatically x,(-6c/5)-b,c is also a solution and similarly another solution is x,b,(-6b/5)-c so when we find b and c as multiples of 5 then we can alternately apply and generate further solutions. I really don't know how far valid is this .

Comment: @ThomasAndrews suppose x,b,c are natural then does the solution set become limited or is still infinite?

Comment: $(b,c,x)=((11 m^2 - 4 m n - 11 n^2)/20, (-m^2 + 4 m n + n^2)/4, m^2 + n^2)$, infinite set of solutions.

Comment: Looks like the general solution is some multiple of $b = 5m^2 - 10mn - 11n^2, c = -11m^2 - 10mn + n^2, x = 4(5m^2 + 6mn + 5n^2)$ (where it might be possible for $b,c,x$ to have a common factor even if $m$ and $n$ don't, so rational multiples might be needed).

Comment: Or, if you use $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ as the base solution, you get $b = -5m^2 - 10mn + n^2, c = m^2 + 10mn + 5n^2, x = 2(5m^2+6mn+5n^2)$.

Comment: An inmediate partial parametrization is given by $(b,c,x)=(n,-n,2n)$ and $(b,c,x)=(n,n,4n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **primitive** integer solutions are
$$   x = 4 u^2 - 2uv - v^2 \, ,  \; \; y= -4 u^2 -2uv + v^2 \, ,  \; \; z=  8 u^2  +  2 v^2   $$

$$   x = 4 u^2 - 2uv - v^2 \, ,  \; \; y= -4 u^2 +6uv - v^2 \, ,  \; \; z=  8 u^2 - 8 uv  +  4 v^2   $$

where we demand $\gcd(u,v) = 1$   and $v$  **odd**.

Note that we may exchange $x,y$  and possibly negate both, so that now $x \geq |y| $

One of the recipes above gives $ z \equiv 2 \pmod 4,$  the other gives $ z \equiv 0 \pmod 4.$

Theorem in Mordell  that a **finite** list of these types of parameterizations gives all

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
   x       y       z  recipe       u       v
   1      -1       2     A         0       1
   1      -1       2    RAW   
   1       1       4     B         1       1
   1       1       4    RAW   
   5      -1      10     A         1       1
   5      -1      10    RAW   
  11       1      26     A         1       3
  11       1      26    RAW   
  11      -5      20     B         2       1
  11      -5      20    RAW   
  19     -11      34     A         2       1
  19     -11      34    RAW   
  19       5      50     A         2       3
  19       5      50    RAW   
  29      11      82     A         2       5
  29      11      82    RAW   
  29     -19      52     B         3       1
  29     -19      52    RAW   
  31     -11      58     A         1       5
  31     -11      58    RAW   
  31      -1      68     B         4       3
  31      -1      68    RAW   
  41      19     122     A         3       5
  41      19     122    RAW   
  41     -29      74     A         3       1
  41     -29      74    RAW   
  55      29     170     A         3       7
  55      29     170    RAW   
  55     -41     100     B         4       1
  55     -41     100    RAW   
  59      11     148     B         6       5
  59      11     148    RAW   
  59     -31     106     A         1       7
  59     -31     106    RAW   
  61     -19     116     B         5       3
  61     -19     116    RAW   
  61      -5     130     A         2       7
  61      -5     130    RAW   
  71      41     226     A         4       7
  71      41     226    RAW   
  71     -55     130     A         4       1
  71     -55     130    RAW   
  79       1     178     A         4       5
  79       1     178    RAW   
  79     -31     146     A         4       3
  79     -31     146    RAW   
  89      55     290     A         4       9
  89      55     290    RAW   
  89     -71     164     B         5       1
  89     -71     164    RAW   
  95      31     260     B         8       7
  95      31     260    RAW   
  95     -59     170     A         1       9
  95     -59     170    RAW   
 101     -11     212     B         7       5
 101     -11     212    RAW   
 101     -29     194     A         2       9
 101     -29     194    RAW   
 109      71     362     A         5       9
 109      71     362    RAW   
 109     -89     202     A         5       1
 109     -89     202    RAW   
 121      19     298     A         5       7
 121      19     298    RAW   
 121     -61     218     A         5       3
 121     -61     218    RAW  
  x       y       z   recipe       u       v
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

[image]

Comment: Can you kindly state the name of the book that has been stated here?

Comment: @The Revolution, Louis Joel Mordell. Diophantine equations. Academic Press, 1969

Comment: Thanks a lot for the name!